# Plotting a Point on a Graph in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have an xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers graph and want to separately plot a single point on the same graph that is unrelated to the data set. The x and y location of the point is separately already stored both in variables in VBA and in cells in excel. The goal is just to plot the point and label it with either the x and y coordinates or a string. Here's the code for the graph so far and the point I want to plot is stored in `"E3"` for the x and `"G3"` for the y:

```
    Dim chart As Range
    Set chart = Range("Q4:R104")
    Dim cht As Object
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(XlChartType:=xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers)
    With cht.chart
        .SetSourceData Source:=chart
        .HasTitle = True
        With .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
            .HasTitle = True
            .AxisTitle.Text = "Y Values"
            .AxisTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 11
        End With
        With .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
            .HasTitle = True
            .AxisTitle.Text = "X Values"
            .AxisTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 12
        End With
        With .ChartArea
            .Height = 350
            .Width = 500
            .Top = 100
            .Left = 425
        End With
    End With
    If check1 = 1 Then
        cht.chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Cubic Spline Graph with Boundary Condition 1"
    ElseIf check1 = 2 Then
        cht.chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Cubic Spline Graph with Boundary Condition 2"
    End If
```

Comment: I think if I were able to add two different data sets with two different graph types it might be doable but I can't quite seem to get the working

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a series to the chart, the series being the point you want to add.

Inside the `With cht.Chart` block...

```
With cht.Chart

    ' other stuff first

    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Name = "New Series"
        .Values = Range("G3")
        .XValues = Range("E3")
        With .Points(1)
            .HasDataLabel = True
            .DataLabel.Caption = "My Label"
        End With
    End With

End With
```